# How to bind data-id instead of id in jquery

Tags: jquery

Good morning,

I have the following code using an ID :

```
$('#signup-country').bind('change keyup', function(){
```

Now i would like to use the data-id instead of a normal id (in this case #signup-country).

How I can bind a data-id please?

I was trying something like this:

```
$('[data-id=' + "signup-country" +']').bind('change keyup', function(){
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('[data-id=signup-country]')` should be sufficient

The quotes after **=** `"signup-country"` are optional.

Also remember. For this to work you are supposed to have the `data-id` attribute in your HTML

```
<input id="signup-country"  data-id="signup-country" />
```

If your element looks like `<input id="signup-country" />` the selector in question will not work.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
 $('[data-id="signup-country"]').bind('change keyup', function(){
 .....
 });
```

`""` quotes are optional..still i prefer it for clearity and readability..

[example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/pDxN9/)